# Why asp web site on IIs10 hangs after migration?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an asp website with framework.net 4. I change the server to 2019 with IIs 10. after migration my web site hangs. my application pool is classic. I check the network but I can not find the reason. I have virtual network for server.

What is the problem? How can I check the truble?

Answer (score 0):

Open the EventView on server and see what are the asp.net errors there.

Usually when you setup a new server, and you have a new pool, the settings on the pool is to stay down if too many errors appears, and if for example can connect to the database, it may stay down...

So find your error on event viewer, then check the settings of you pool to see if have set to stay down after some errors.